# ImportError when using my code in pythonanywhere

Tags: python, pythonanywhere

Okay I've been stuck for a while trying to use my own code in pythonanywhere, I keep getting the `ImportError: No module named mysite.settings` issue. I am using the standard code that was provided by pythonanywhere in my wsgi file:

```
import os
import sys

path = os.path.expanduser('~/mysite')
if path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(path)
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'mysite.settings'
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
from django.contrib.staticfiles.handlers import StaticFilesHandler
application = StaticFilesHandler(get_wsgi_application())
```

Originally I create a 'mysite' project in their bash console, thinking I could just copy and paste everything from my code into the new mysite directory. But that would take too long. So I cloned my own git repo and just renamed the directory to `mysite` and also placed a second `mysite` folder inside that one (just like the original `mysite` directory). I just assumed this would work, as long as my `settings.py` file was in the same place. But it isn't working, it's not even finding the file, what has changed?

directory: `home/charles125/mysite/mysite` it worked before with the django app I made in their bash console, but not with my own app

Comment: There is a help page for this sort of issue here: [http://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/DebuggingImportError/](http://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/DebuggingImportError/)

Comment: @Glenn read that already and still having the issue, I'm not sure why it won't even import the module when it has the exact same name

Comment: If you're using that exact WSGI glue code, is there a file called `/home/charles125/mysite/mysite/settings.py`?  Have you reloaded the site after making your code changes?